# iOS only setting app

Tags: ios, tweak

I would like to know how it's possible to develop an app that provide only some settings in the iOS native setting app like a lot of cydia tweak without have an icon on the springboard ?
My goal is just to have some switch and button who send command on my local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS your app must have an icon on the springboard.

You can add your app to the Settings App to allow for changing your app settings.  The catch is that when these settings are changed, they do not launch your app too send it actions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't do it with a normal application.

Comment: But is it possible to develop a cydia tweak containing 2 table view, a first with 8 table cell, each containing a label and a switch and when i click on the switch it will send a different command line via SSH switch the state of the clicked switch (on/off), and a second 4 with table cell containing just a button that send multiple command ?